# map reduce job execution stop on map task at 67%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I have created map reduce job in java on eclipse.I have create map reduce job for wordcount which reads data(approximate 7453215 record - 670MB) from sql server and store result back to sql server.I have created HDInsight cluster on azure which has 2 head node and 3 worker nodes.Each node has 4 cores and 14GB RAM.Map Reduce job running successfully on local but while i am submitting jar file of map reduce job to HDInsight cluster on azure then it stoppped on map task at 67%.

here is the log,

> 17/12/01 13:23:20 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application
>    History server at headnodehost/10.0.0.20:10200 17/12/01 13:23:21 INFO
>    client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider: Looking for the active
>   RM in [rm1, rm2]... 17/12/01 13:23:21 INFO
>   client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider: Found active RM [rm2]
>    17/12/01 13:23:21 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop
>    command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool
>   interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
>    17/12/01 13:23:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
>    17/12/01 13:23:37 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for
>    job: job_1512119994740_0011 17/12/01 13:23:37 INFO
>    impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application
>    application_1512119994740_0011 17/12/01 13:23:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:
>    The url to track the job:
>    http://hn1-hdpclu.53o3id15rwte5en44vyo02sv0h.dx.internal.cloudapp.net:8088/proxy/application_1512119994740_0011/
>    17/12/01 13:23:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:
>    job_1512119994740_0011 17/12/01 13:23:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job
>    job_1512119994740_0011 running in uber mode : false
>
> 17/12/01 13:23:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>
> 17/12/01 13:24:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
>
> 17/12/01 13:24:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%

Error:

> 2017-12-02 07:09:17,697 INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #1]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler:
>   Processing the event EventType: TASK_ABORT 2017-12-02 07:09:17,697
>   WARN [CommitterEvent Processor #1]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Output
>   Path is null in abortTask() 2017-12-02 07:09:17,699 INFO
>   [AsyncDispatcher event handler]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from
>   FAIL_TASK_CLEANUP to FAILED 2017-12-02 07:09:17,708 INFO [Thread-56]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: 1 failures
>   on node 10.0.0.11 2017-12-02 07:09:17,709 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event
>   handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000000_1 TaskAttempt Transitioned from
>   NEW to UNASSIGNED 2017-12-02 07:09:17,709 INFO [Thread-56]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Added
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000000_1 to list of failed maps
>   2017-12-02 07:09:17,721 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000001_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from
>   FAIL_CONTAINER_CLEANUP to FAIL_TASK_CLEANUP 2017-12-02 07:09:17,728
>   INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #2]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler:
>   Processing the event EventType: TASK_ABORT 2017-12-02 07:09:17,728
>   WARN [CommitterEvent Processor #2]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Output
>   Path is null in abortTask() 2017-12-02 07:09:17,728 INFO
>   [AsyncDispatcher event handler]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000001_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from
>   FAIL_TASK_CLEANUP to FAILED 2017-12-02 07:09:17,729 INFO [Thread-56]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: 2 failures
>   on node 10.0.0.11 2017-12-02 07:09:17,729 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event
>   handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000001_1 TaskAttempt Transitioned from
>   NEW to UNASSIGNED 2017-12-02 07:09:17,729 INFO [Thread-56]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Added
>   attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000001_1 to list of failed maps
>   2017-12-02 07:09:18,234 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Before
>   Scheduling: PendingReds:1 ScheduledMaps:2 ScheduledReds:0
>   AssignedMaps:3 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:0 CompletedReds:0
>   ContAlloc:3 ContRel:0 HostLocal:0 RackLocal:0 2017-12-02 07:09:18,240
>   INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor:
>   getResources() for application_1512191608534_0003: ask=1 release= 0
>   newContainers=0 finishedContainers=1 resourcelimit= knownNMs=1 2017-12-02 07:09:18,240 INFO [RMCommunicator
>   Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator:
>   Received completed container container_1512191608534_0003_01_000002
>   2017-12-02 07:09:18,240 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator:
>   Recalculating schedule, headroom= 2017-12-02
>   07:09:18,240 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Reduce
>   slow start threshold not met. completedMapsForReduceSlowstart 1
>   2017-12-02 07:09:18,240 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl:
>   Diagnostics report from attempt_1512191608534_0003_m_000000_0:
>   Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on
>   request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code
>   143

Comment: `The URL to track the job`  tells you the actual problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the log of mapreduce job in error part...please review it.

Comment: `FileOutputCommitter: Output Path is null`... That sounds like important... I'm not sure where you got this log, but I would check the actual map attempt logs, and the stderr output

Comment: I found the solution.While reading data from sql server it store same data to all node(i have 3 nodes).670 MB file data reside on 3 nodes so it becomes 1.96 GB file.so it took long time to execute the process...Thank for your response.